# Springboot actuator DB health check

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, datasource, spring-boot-actuator

I need to change frequency to check DB health in springboot actuator.Default DB health check query gets executed in every millisecond. i want to make this query to be executed after every 1 min instead of in milliseconds.
Is there any way to customize it?

Comment: "DB health in springboot actuator"? this seems like a custom health contributor. you might want to provide a lot more details here

Comment: I agree with Eugene, this seems like you would need to define your own custom health check in order to set the frequency since, it doesn't seem that spring allows you to alter such a value. This [article](https://www.amitph.com/custom-health-check-spring-boot-actuator/) shows a few examples but, you would have to figure out how to set the frequency yourself through a delay() or some other more optimal method.

Answer (score 3):

Actually actuator only executes when you consumed the api. If you want your actuator updated, you can do two things first is to call the api every minute, another one is to create a custom health check and enable scheduling.

```java
@SpringBootApplication

@EnableScheduling

public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication .class, args);
    }
}
```

```java
@Service
public class CustomService {

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 60000)
    public Object getResultFromQuery() {
        // call your query
    }

}
```

```java
@Component
public class HealthCustomCheck implements HealthIndicator {

    private final CustomService customService;

    public HealthCustomCheck(CustomService customService) {
        this.customService = customService;
    }


    @Override
    public Health health() {
        return Health.up().withDetail("yourQuery", customService.getResultFromQuery().toString()).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you...got you...really helpful